# get data with find in mongoose and node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, find

I have a problem returning some data from a db in mongodb. I put you in situation.

I have a file called **db.js**, which has the following content:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var libro = mongoose.Schema({
        titulo: String,
        estado: String,
        autor: String,
        genero: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('estanteria', libro);
```

I have another file called **estanteria.js** that has the following content:

```
const Libreria = require('./db');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/libreria', (err) => {
    if(err) throw err;

    console.log("Conexión a db correcta");
});

...

function allBooks(){
    var libros = Libreria.find({}) 

    return libros;
}

exports.allBooks = allBooks;
```

The problem I have in the function **allBooks()**, I do not know how to return the contents of the collection in an array of objects, and then display it on the web. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Inside allBooks function add a callback function to return after **find** operation.

```
function allBooks(){
    Libreria.find({}).exec(function(error, records) {
        if (!error) {
            res.send({
                success : true,
                records : records
            });
        } else {
            console.log(error);
            res.send({
                success : false,
                error : error
            });
        } 
});
}

exports.allBooks = allBooks;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Libreria.find({})` is an async operation, you need to use Promises way to handle this. As shown below:

Libreria.find returns a promise and you can handle the resolve state of this promise in .then method and if any error occurs it will be done in .catch

```
    function allBooks(){    
        Libreria.find({}) 
           .then(function(books) {
              return books;
           })
           .catch(function(error){
              return error;
           })
    }

    // An exmaple router handler as follow:
     router.get("/posts", function(req, res){
       allBooks()
         .then(function(records){
           res.json({status: true, records})
         })
        .catch(function(error){
           res.json({status: false, error })
         });
     })
```

> Read more about mongoose promises: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
>
> Promises in general: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.stringify()` to encode libros in a jhson format then write it as an response to the request ( The request recieved by the server )